# How to change tabcontrol index with different radiobuttons? C#

Tags: c#, foreach, radio-button, tabcontrol

```
private void radioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton1.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        else if (radioButton2.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        else if (radioButton3.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
        else if (radioButton4.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;
        else if (radioButton5.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 4;
        else if (radioButton6.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 5;
        else if (radioButton7.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 6;
        else if (radioButton8.Checked) tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 7;
    }
```

As you can see, I am changing my tab pages with radiobuttons using the EventHandler(). I was wondering, how can I simplify this "else if" structure. Probably I'll need a foreach(), but I can't find out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `Tag` for each radio button bind with an index.

```
radioButton1.Tag = 0;
radioButton2.Tag = 1;
...

RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
if(radioButton.Checked)
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = (int)radioButton.Tag;
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tagged them all with "foreach", so now the code looks even more pleasant.